# Indesign - Need to split between only 2 text boxes

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, script

first time here.

I'm working in Indesign and I was wondering if anyone knew how to split text between just two text frames/boxes.

To be clear, I'm not trying to unlink text boxes, but split them. I know you can split **all** text boxes using the script in the scripts window but it splits the whole story. I'm just looking to split from the text box linked above/ahead of another one. (think of it like a knife tool. lol.)

Is there another script out there I need? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand.. if you hit the Enter key (not the Return Key -- Command/Ctrl+Return if you have no Enter key), it will force text to jump to the next text frame. Is that what you are after?

Comment: It kinda sounds like this is the information you're looking for: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/threading-text.html

Answer (score 3):

You simply draw another text frame and link the text to that frame:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There are many scripts that can achieve what you want.
I do use simple and efficient [StorySplitter](https://indesignsecrets.com/downloads/StorySplitter.jsx).
You can also check out extensive article about this topic [here](https://indesignsecrets.com/how-to-split-long-story-into-smaller-pieces-unthreading-middle-story.php)

Comment: I'm sure anonymous downvoter would have a better understanding of the question and a better solution to offer... I just can't wait to read it...